# Shiny - How to tell client when a process is done

Tags: r, text, shiny, render, observers

I'm completely new to Shiny and I can't get a textOutput to render when I want it to.

```
observeEvent(input$btnPersistencia, {
  output$txtProtActual <- renderText("PROCESSING...")
  print("This does print in console")

  #SomeCodeHere that takes about 10 seconds to finish

  output$txtProtActual <- renderText(paste("Archivo Persistencia Actual: ", basename(values$file), "\n Dim: ", isolate(input$sliderDimension), "\n Filtr: ", isolate(input$txtMaxFil)))
})
```

The text isn't showing "Processing..." while #SomeCodeHere is running. I really don't understand why. Shouldn't it work?

**The text is only rendered AFTER the observeEvent is finished**. I know this because if I remove the SECOND renderText(), the text takes the value "Processing..." when the processing is over.

If this is the normal behaviour, is there a way to force the render before the observeEvent is over?

EDIT:

Is there another (any) way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Maybe a progress bar? http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: Post your comment as a complete answer and I'll check it as the right answer. This does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer (thanks!)

The article about Progress Bars is [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) and the reference [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html).
Here's your code with the progress bar:

```
observeEvent(input$btnPersistencia, {
   withProgress(message = 'PROCESSING...', value = 0, {
       incProgress(1/2)
       #SomeCodeHere that takes about 10 seconds to finish
       Sys.sleep(10)
   })

   output$txtProtActual <- renderText({
     paste("Archivo Persistencia Actual: ", basename(values$file),
       "\n Dim: ", isolate(input$sliderDimension),
       "\n Filtr: ", isolate(input$txtMaxFil)
     )
   })
 })
```

Although it's not related to your question, I've noticed you've placed an `output` inside an `observeEvent` with some `isolate` wrapping `inputs`.

One of the shiny developers talks about observers in the [first two videos of shiny's 2016 conference](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/). It helped me understand a lot better how to use observers and I thought you might find it useful. :]